# How to write Linux kernel module for serial communication to arduino?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arduino, serial-port

I have got Arduino MEGA 2560. What I would like to do is to send a signal to Arduino via serial port to light specified LED up. However, I cannot find any documentation about this. What steps should I follow?

I think first, I need to compile the driver of Arduino and add it to Linux kernel. Second, I have to find some header files to use them in module. Then, I have to find functions to start serial communication and to light LEDs up. However, these are just my thoughts.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you *required* to write a kernel module? Because user-space applications should have no problem communicating with any serial device you could think of. A serial device can be opened and read from/written to just like any other character device or file.

Comment: Actually I am not developing a project. It is just my assignment at university.

Comment: You didn't really answer to the point. Does your assignment *specifically address* writing a kernel module? Anything user space would be way simpler and work just as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, any user-space application will not be accepted. So, I have to write linux kernel module to this problem.

Comment: That's a stupid constraint.

Comment: @Olaf I am taking "System Programming" lesson. That's why this is the constraint.

Comment: There are much more reasonable system-programming tasks. Writing a serial driver is none of them. Anyway, this question is off-topic. You should talk to your tutor for - well - tutoring.

Comment: I am student now. I know there are many. Remember the time when you are a student. By the way, this is just an assignment to learn it.

Comment: Is there an existing tty driver for the serial port hardware? If so, you could use `filp_open` in your kernel module to open the existing serial port if you know its filename. See "drivers/staging/comedi/drivers/serial2002.c" for an example, but this sort of thing is a very ugly trick, and involves switching memory segments at various places to use kernel memory in function calls that expect user memory.

Answer (score 0):

The arduino-mega (the one with ATmega2560) documentation is here:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega2560#documentation

The serial communication via UART:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial

Since there are other ways for serial communication with the ATmega please read the documentation [above] and compare that to your exercise sheet.

I think such a kernel module is already available - and used by the arduino-ide.